# Silent crash when pulling down on FlatList React Native Android

Tags: android, reactjs, list, scroll, native

I am working on a legacy react native app using react-native 0.59.9. I am using a FlatList to show a list of podcasts. If I pull down on the list (as if I were trying to refresh) the app crashes, and I don't get any logs. I don't have any code implemented to do a pull to refresh. The FlatList is not inside a ScrollView. I can scroll down but if I get back to the top of the list it crashes. I am at a loss. Below is the code. (The typos are from the previous developer and I haven't gotten around to fixing them yet) Any ideas on how I can track this down, or what the cause may be? I have attached android studio to the emulator to see what logcat shows, but I don't see anything that clues me in. It works just fine on iOS.

```
return (
      <View>
        {this.renderPtsModal()}
        <Col style={{ flexDirection: 'row', maxHeight: 40 }}>
          <Row style={{ height: 40,marginLeft:10 }}>
            {this.renderFilter()}

          </Row>
          <Row style={{ height: 40,}}>
            {this.renderSearchModal()}
          </Row>
        </Col>
        {this.renderModalFilter()}
        <Col>
          <Row>
            <Popover
              contentStyle={{ alignItems: 'center', width: 170, padding: 8, backgroundColor: 'rgba(180, 209, 35, 1)', borderRadius: 8, }}
              arrowStyle={{ borderTopColor: 'rgba(180, 209, 35, 1)', }}
              backgroundStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' }}
              visible={this.state.showPopover}
              fromRect={this.state.popoverAnchor}
              // onClose={this.closePopover}
              placement="bottom">
              <Row style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                <Col style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end', }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.closePopover}>
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(180, 209, 35, 0.8)', width: 40, height: 20, }}>
                      <Image source={require('../../images/close.png')} resizeMode={'stretch'} style={{ width: 13, height: 13, alignSelf: 'flex-end' }} />
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  <Text style={{ color: '#0B254B', fontSize: 13, }}>Did You Know...</Text>
                </Col>
                <Col style={{ paddingTop: 10 }}>
                  <Text style={{ color: '#0B254B', fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 18 }}>
                    You can listen to podcasts, watch videos and answer questions to earn points!
                         </Text>
                </Col>
                <Col style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 10 }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.CheckBoxPress}>
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(180, 209, 35, 0.8)', borderRadius: 0.5, width: 16, height: 16, borderColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1 }}>
                      <Image source={require('../../images/checkSelectBox.png')} resizeMode={'stretch'} style={{ width: 13, height: 13, display: this.state.isCheck }} />
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <Text style={{ color: '#0B254B', fontSize: 12, marginLeft: 5, }}>
                    Don't Show Again
                </Text>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Popover>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.postcast_data}
              extraData={this.state}
              keyExtractor={item => item.guid["#text"]}
              renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderRow(item, index)}/>
          </Row>
        </Col>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I finally narrowed down the issue to a webview inside the renderrow. A webview was unnecessary for the purpose, so replacing it with Text solved the crash.